# Catch Errors during server startup in a Spring MVC Application

Tags: spring-mvc, error-handling

I am working on a Spring MVC application that tries to initialize certain objects during server startup by connecting to a database.

I would like to alert my application support team by writing to a log file (that is monitored by the application support team), whenever there is an issue during server startup caused by either of the scenarios listed below.

- The server could not auto wire any of the beans specified in the applicationContext.
- The database is down and could not connect.

I would like to know how to trap the errors in the scenarios listed above in an application server / database server/driver agnostic way. We use different servers between dev (jboss) and production (web sphere) and also, is there a way to log the sqlexception in a database server/driver agnostic way?

I was hoping to catch the sqlException in the data loader class that is attempting to connect to database, but I do not want to log all sqlException as ALERTS to application support team. Also, if I have to to check for a specific sqlErrorCode, will that be specific to the database driver used by the application? Tomorrow, when I have another class that loads different data, I have to repeat this process again. Instead, is there a simpler way to do this across the application, whenever server does not start or connect to the database.

Can aspects to used to trap these errors (both server startup and database connection issue)?

The exceptions that I am referring to, here are

- when auto wiring fails (in this case, by an invalid datasource)
    `22:06:51,767|FLH|||ERROR|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:308)||Thread-3|Context initialization failed
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Unable to get managed connection for jdbc/mydatasource; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for jdbc/mydatasource)`
- when it cannot connect to database 
   `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
  at   org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:229)
  ... 146 more
  Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the     connection
  at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:328)
  at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:421)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:630)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:206)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
  ... 151 more
  Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: server1.somewhere.com
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
  at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:127)
  at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:126)
  at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:306)
  ... 156 more`

Answer (score 0):

@aprajitha - you can achievethis  by

1. Classify the errors which are required to be reported.
2. Implement Log4j 2 - this gives lots of options to effectively control logging

For example you can place specific errors in specific file upon the matching filter criteria. In this way you segregate the exception "Reporting" dependency from the code though simple logger configuration.

I am pretty sure that your first error will never occur in the main region else it will be a deploy fail ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using log4j 1.4 and have a custom log level, named ALERT to classify errors that need immediate attention. What I am struggling to find is where to log the errors, not how to log the errors. When there is a database exception of the nature that the host cannot be reached, I need to log an ALERT. I need to do this at an application level and not at every controller/ class level.